# Confusion about Android SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have 2 radio groups from main activity and I want to save their states and to use the data and determine how the next activity looks.

**EDIT:** updating the getTapCheckedOption() code.

in mainActivity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    SharedPreferences radioButtonPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = radioButtonPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.tap_checked), tapRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.time_checked), timeRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    editor.apply();
    ...}
```

in SecondActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    SharedPreferences radioButtonPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    getTapCheckedOption(radioButtonPref);
    getTimeCheckedOption(radioButtonPref);
    ...}
```

my 2 methods in SecondActivity:

```
public void getTapCheckedOption(SharedPreferences sharePref) {
    int checkedId = sharePref.getInt(getString(R.string.tap_checked), 0);
    switch (checkedId) {
    //2 buttons have always been there, if I choose one option the other will disappear.
        case R.id.one_finger_radio_button:
            twoFingerTap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case R.id.two_finger_radio_button:
            oneFingerTap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
    }
}
public void getTimeCheckedOption(SharedPreferences sharePref) {
    int checkedId = sharePref.getInt(getString(R.string.time_checked), 0);
    switch (checkedId) {
        case R.id.thirty_second_radio_button:
            //countdown 30s
            break;
        case R.id.fifteen_second_radio_button:
            //countdown 15s
            break;
    }
}
```

When I run the app, choose the options from the radio group and click done to move to the SecondActivity, nothing happens, the `checkedID` inside my 2 methods return `-1`. Shouldn't it either be the ID of the radio button I clicked or `0`? Is this the correct use of SharedPreference?

And also if I set a radio button to be checked by default in MainActivity, for example

```
oneFingerButton.setChecked(true);
```

the `checkedID` always return the ID of that radio button, regardless of option changes.

Comment: Show `tapRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`'s code.

Comment: @goodev sorry I don't understand what you are asking, `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` is a default method for `RadioGroup`. Did you mean something else?

Comment: The code you show for mainActivity should be inside OnClick() of "done'" rather than in onCreate(). You are now saving the status of radio buttons when mainActivity is started. Hope that helps!

Comment: @duyanhhoang Sorry, I mean where you call `tapRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` method. See  @i-a-mok 's comment

Comment: @I_A_Mok 's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is, using `boolean` instead of `Id` and pass data using `Intent` instead of `SharedPreferences` as in

FirstActivty

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("isOneFinger",oneFingerButton.isChecked());
intent.putExtra("isThirtySecond",thirtyButton.isChecked());
startActivity(intent);
```

SecondActivity

```
 boolean isOneFinger = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isOneFinger",false);
   boolean isThirtySecond = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isThirtySecond",false);

   if(isOneFinger){
       // one finger pressed
   }else{
       // two finger pressed
   }

   if(isThirtySecond ){
       // 30s timer
   }else{
       // 15s timer
   }
```